# Windows 10 upgrade changed my Notepad++ icon

Tags: windows, notepad++, windows-10

When I originally installed Notepad++, I selected the option for Notepad++ to use the original Notepad++ icon rather than the new one.

Since my OS update from Windows 7 to Windows 10, Notepad++ now displays the *new* icon rather than the old icon:

[image: The new Notepad++ icon]

Anyone know how to bring back the old icon without uninstalling Notepad++?

Comment: It's not a difficult install, so it's probably a better use of your time to uninstall it and reinstall it. I'm sure there's some other solution, but it's like a 30 second install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link here: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Icon_Of_Notepad%2B%2B

> These are provided by the application and looked up by Windows when it
>   starts it, so changing an icon at runtime is not an option. Changing
>   the icon of an executeble is possible using some extra free shell
>   extensions or tools like ResHacker.

So if you are adamant about not uninstalling, you should look into ResHacker

Comment: I am afraid you are right, Kenneth. Thanks for your perseverance. Another thought is that the Windows 10 upgrade resets something in the registry (that's where I was thinking the issue would be resolved). I notice in Win7, the Notepad++ icon is smaller than the Notepad++ icon in Win10 (16x16 vs 32x32 or something). Perhaps Notepad++ doesn't provide a smaller icon to Windows 10, or perhaps something changed (obvious it did) when we interact with Windows 10 when we give it instructions on how to visualize our application icons. (we=developers)

Comment: Can you make this the answer then. With so many answers it may be confusing when others might have the same problem and try to find out the resolution

Answer (score 2):

It's not a difficult install, so it's probably a better use of your time to uninstall it and reinstall it. I'm sure there's some other solution, but it's like a 30 second install.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the repair on Notepad++? I believe it should be an option when you run that tool.

Updated: 
Try right clicking on the icon and selecting `Properties`. From there, select `Shortcut` and then the button `Change Icon`. You should be able to change the icon from there

Comment: No "repair" option on the setup, only "uninstall"!

Comment: Try right clicking on the icon and selecting `Properties`. From there, select `Shortcut` and then the button `Change Icon`. You should be able to change the icon from there

Comment: Yes, you can change the icon of a shortcut, but you can't change the icon of a non-shortcut. The Shortcut tab in Properties doesn't exist for a non-shortcut.